# Asp.net 5 global.json file not working with relative path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

I am trying to add a `DNX` project to my solution by means of `global.json` but i can't get it working by relative path.With absolute path it works as expected.

This is what i am trying (which fails) :

```
"projects": [
    "test",
    "src",
    "src\\Web\\Plugins"  
  ],
```

but following is working :

```
 "projects": [
        "test",
        "src",
        "E:\\XX\\YY\\src\\Web\\Plugins"  
      ],
```

i am using ASP.NET 5 rc1-final.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using slash (/) instead of backslash ()?

```
"projects": [
    "test",
    "src",
    "src/Web/Plugins"  
  ],
```

I'm not sure if this matters, but the global.json files that get automatically generated use /.

Answer (score 0):

have tried adding ".\" to point to the current directory.

so your path would look like

```
"projects": [
    "test",
    "src",
    ".\\src\\Web\\Plugins"  
  ],
```